# doc2id mapping in gensim

Tags: python, similarity, gensim

I am using gensim to construct an LSI corpus and then apply query similarity following gensim tutorials ([tut1](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html), [tut2](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut2.html) n [tut3](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut3.html))

My issue is that when I try to calcualte query similarity as shown in the code below I get the result in form of (docID, simScore) tuples.

I need to use that **docID** to retrive a **string representation of the document**. (similar to the token2id mapping in the `corpora.Dictionary`)

Googling that I could not find anything useful

**My Code for searching**

```
    def search(self):
    #Load necessary information
    dictionary = corpora.Dictionary.load('dictionary.dict')
    corpus_tfidf = corpora.MmCorpus('corpus.mm') # comes from the first tutorial, "From strings to vectors"
    #print(corpus_tfidf)

    #Generate LSI model
    #lsi = models.LsiModel(corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=2)
    lsi = LsiModel(corpus_tfidf,num_topics=2)

    #construct index
    index = similarities.MatrixSimilarity(lsi[corpus_tfidf]) # transform corpus to LSI space and index it

    #Construct query vector
    doc = "Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications"
    vec_bow = dictionary.doc2bow(doc.lower().split())
    vec_lsi = lsi[vec_bow] # convert the query to LSI space

    #Calcualte similarity
    sims = index[vec_lsi] # perform a similarity query against the corpus
    sims = sorted(enumerate(sims), key=lambda item: -item[1])

    print(sims) # print sorted (document number, similarity score) 2-tuples
```

**Results sample**

```
[(1, 0.9962855), (4, 0.99420911), (2, 0.98064679), (3, 0.97580492), (0, 0.9755646), (8, 0.34740543), (6, 0.1566827), (7, 0.15566549), (5, 0.13825497)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a documents corpus, which i guess is a list of texts, also you have a similarities list, containing docs id's. So you can map id's to texts with something like this:

```
corpus = ['a','b','c']
sims = [(0,0.1),(1,0.2),(2,0.3)]
labeled_sims = [(corpus[id],sim) for id,sim in sims]
```

which will return:

```
[('a',0.1),('b',0.2),('c',0.3)]
```

or alternatively you can just do so before sorting:

```
labeled_sims = zip(corpus,sims)
```

which will return:

```
[('a',(0,0.1)),('b',(1,0.2)),('c',(2,0.3))]
```

which can be further sorted with:

```
labeled_sims = sorted(enumerate(labeled_sims), key=lambda item: -item[1][1])
```